# Do any Javascript IDEs support automatic error highlighting (like the Eclipse Java IDE)?

Tags: javascript, ide

Are there any Javascript IDEs that support automatic error highlighting? I want to enable automatic highlighting, but the Geany IDE doesn't support it. (I mean that it should be possible to see a line that produced an error immediately after the error was encountered in a script).

Comment: i believe xcode has the ability to do that, what are you using, mac or windows?'

Comment: I'm using Linux right now, but I also have Windows installed on my computer.

Comment: It appears that Aptana supports this feature: https://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/discussions/questions/935-how-to-highlight-errors-in-javascript-or-html

Comment: Also, the cloud9 ide makes it possible to quickly jump to an error (which can't yet be done using Geany.)

Comment: I now realize that this question is off-topic here. It should instead be migrated to http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eclipse supports syntax and error highlighting for JavaScript. Just be sure the [JavaScript Development Tools (JSDT)](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jsdt/) are installed.

If you have a package of Eclipse that doesn't include the JavaScript Development Tools, go to Help->Install New Software... Select the repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno from the dropdown menu (or add it if it's not there). (This is assuming you're running the latest Juno version of Eclipse. Other versions will have a similar repository though.)

You can type "JavaScript" in the filter text box or locate JavaScript Development Tools under Programming Languages. Check the box next to the tools, hit next, agree to the licenses, finish and you're good to go once Eclipse restarts.

You will likely want to change to the JavaScript perspective for an optimal experience while programming in that language. Window->Open Perspective->Other... Select JavaScript in the list  and hit OK.

Comment: Do any other JavaScript IDEs have this feature (besides Eclipse)?

Comment: Also, how can the JavaScript development tools be installed in Eclipse?

Comment: I added info on how to install JSDT in Eclipse as well as change the perspective for JavaScript programming.

Comment: I found out that it's also possible to install Eclipse plugins from the command line: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7163970/how-do-you-automate-the-installation-of-eclipse-plugins-with-command-line

Comment: I found out that the error highlighter for Eclipse and Aptana can't point out the use of non-existent variables. I wonder if there are any other IDEs that can do this?